# How to copy in field if query returns it blank?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am writing query
from two different tables.

Table A and Table B

Here is Query.

```
select 
        A.OUT_NUM,
        A.TIMESTAMP,
        A.LAST_name,
        A.event_type, 
        A.comments,
        B.name
   from TABLEA A
   left outer join TABLEB B ON A.feed_id = B.id
   where A.OUT_NUM = '12345'
   and A.event_type In ('cause','status')
```

`B.NAME` is not null when `event_type = xyz` else it will be null

I only want to see when `event_type in ('CAUSE','STATUS')` but also want to see name field but not empty.

second table is what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but I've no idea what _"is there a way to copy all data in name field when it is blank."_ means... can you provide some sample data so we can see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please see updated question. I only want to see where event_type = cause & status but I don't want `name` to be blank.

Comment: Yes, that's a lot clearer @Mowgli. As it stands you're effectively humped though. You can do a second LEFT OUTER JOIN to pick up the name but your problem seems to be caused by your database. Why isn't NAME a OUT_NUM level field and why doesn't it have a NOT NULL constraint in that table.

Comment: So you want the `name` value from an `XYZ` record for the same `out_num`... or the same `feed_id`? Will there only ever be one value like that?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes that is what I want and I am wishing there will be only 1 value, I haven't ran into case where I have more than 1, but right now my goal is only 1. Ben I  believe name only has data when event_type is xyz.

Comment: Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making some assumptions about your data as in comments, particularly about how to match and pick a substitute `name` value; and with some dummy data that I think matches yours:

```
create table tablea(out_num number,
    equip_name varchar2(5),
    event_type varchar2(10),
    comments varchar2(10),
    timestamp date, feed_id number);

create table tableb(id number, name varchar2(10));

alter session set nls_date_format = 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI';

insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'abcd', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:12'), 1);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'abcd', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:11'), 1);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'abcd', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:06'), 1);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'abcd', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:06'), 1);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'SUB', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:11'), 2);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'SUB', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:12'), 2);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 3);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 3);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 3);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 3);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 3);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:03'), 3);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'CAUSE', 'APPLE', to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 4);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'CAUSE', 'APPLE', to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 4);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'CAUSE', 'APPLE', to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 4);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'STATUS', 'BOOKS', to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 5);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'STATUS', 'BOOKS', to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 5);
insert into tablea values (12345, null, 'STATUS', 'BOOKS', to_date('02/11/2013 11:03'), 5);

insert into tableb values(3, 'LION');
```

This gets your result:

```
select * from (
    select a.out_num,
        a.timestamp,
        a.equip_name,
        a.event_type,
        a.comments,
        coalesce(b.name,
            first_value(b.name)
                over (partition by a.out_num
                    order by b.name nulls last)) as name
    from tablea a
    left outer join tableb b on a.feed_id = b.id
    where a.out_num = '12345'
    and a.event_type in ('CAUSE', 'STATUS', 'XYZ')
)
where event_type in ('CAUSE', 'STATUS');

   OUT_NUM TIMESTAMP          EQUIP_NAME EVENT_TYPE COMMENTS   NAME     
---------- ------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     12345 02/11/2013 11:03              STATUS     BOOKS      LION       
     12345 02/11/2013 11:13              STATUS     BOOKS      LION       
     12345 02/11/2013 11:13              STATUS     BOOKS      LION       
     12345 02/11/2013 11:13              CAUSE      APPLE      LION       
     12345 02/11/2013 11:13              CAUSE      APPLE      LION       
     12345 02/11/2013 11:13              CAUSE      APPLE      LION
```

The inner query includes `XYZ` and uses the analytic `first_value()` function to pick a `name` if the directly matched value is `null` - the `coalesce` may not be necessary  if there really will never be a direct match. (You might also need to adjust the `partition by` or `order by` clauses if the assumptions are wrong). The outer query just strips out the `XYZ` records since you don't want those.

---

If you want to get a `name` value from any matching record then just remove the filter in the inner query.

But now you're perhaps more likely to have more than one non-null record; this will give you one that matches `a.feed_id` if it exists, or the 'first' one (alphabetically, ish) for that `out_num` if it doesn't. You could order by `b.id` instead, or any other column in `tableb`; ordering by anything in `tablea` would need a different solution. If you'll only have one possible match anyway then it doesn't really matter and you can leave out the `order by`, though it's better to have it anyway.

If I add some more data for a different `out_num`:

```
insert into tablea values (12346, null, 'abcd', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:11'), 1);
insert into tablea values (12346, null, 'SUB', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:12'), 2);
insert into tablea values (12346, null, 'XYZ', null, to_date('02/11/2013 11:13'), 6);
insert into tablea values (12346, null, 'CAUSE', 'APPLE', to_date('02/11/2013 11:14'), 4);
insert into tablea values (12346, null, 'STATUS', 'BOOKS', to_date('02/11/2013 11:15'), 5);

insert into tableb values(1, 'TIGER');
```

...then this - which just has the filter dropped, and I've left out the `coalesce` this time - gives the same answer for `12345`, and this for `12346`:

```
select * from (
    select a.out_num,
        a.timestamp,
        a.equip_name,
        a.event_type,
        a.comments,
        first_value(b.name)
            over (partition by a.out_num
                order by b.name nulls last) as name
    from tablea a
    left outer join tableb b on a.feed_id = b.id
)
where out_num = '12346'
and event_type in ('CAUSE', 'STATUS');

   OUT_NUM TIMESTAMP          EQUIP_NAME EVENT_TYPE COMMENTS   NAME     
---------- ------------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     12346 02/11/2013 11:14              CAUSE      APPLE      TIGER      
     12346 02/11/2013 11:15              STATUS     BOOKS      TIGER
```

... where `TIGER` is linked to `abcd`, not `XYZ`.

Comment: Alex, very soon users will get used to you and others creating sample data for them and will downvote us for not doing this for them. This user already wrote to me that he expected a query w/out posting sample and he/she gave me a favor by not downvoting...

Comment: @Art - that's depressing. I thought someone had commented on putting an image of the data rather than something we can copy/recreate, but that must have been a different question. I should have done a simple cut-down example really.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, I haven't had chance to see Art's solution but Alex's worked way I wanted and next time I will post sample data.

Comment: @AlexPoole I know this is getting complicated, but is there a way to modify this, right now we are looking for when event_type is XYZ, but I just found out sometimes there no data in column Name then event_type is xyz, it is there when event_type is abcd. so is there a way to make it look whole column Name if there is data in it and not looking at event_type? let me know if I make any sense if not I can open new question with screenshots.

Comment: @Mowgli - I've added an updated version, based on the assumption there will only ever be one `name` match. (Also, for future questions, please don't post screen shots of data or code, post text that can be copied and used - makes it much easier to test a solution).

Answer (score 1):

Use NVL() and LAG() functions.

General example using my sample data. This query fills out blank rows with data - see first_exam and last_exam columns:

```
SELECT id, name, proc_date, proc_type, first_exam_date
     , NVL(prev_exam_date, LAG(prev_exam_date) OVER (ORDER BY name, proc_date)) last_exam_date
  FROM
   (
   SELECT id, name, proc_date, proc_type, first_exam_date
     , NVL(first_exam_date, LAG(first_exam_date) OVER (ORDER BY name, proc_date) ) prev_exam_date
    FROM
  (
  SELECT id
       , name
       , proc_date
       , proc_type
      , (SELECT MIN(proc_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name, proc_date)
           FROM stack_test WHERE proc_type LIKE 'Exam%' AND a.id = id 
       ) first_exam_date
   FROM stack_test a
  ));
  ID    NAME    PROC_DATE    PROC_TYPE    FIRST_EXAM_DATE    LAST_EXAM_DATE
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    George    1/1/2013    ExamA             1/1/2013      1/1/2013
  2    George    1/3/2013    TreatmentA                      1/1/2013
  3    George    1/5/2013    TreatmentB                      1/1/2013
  4    George    2/1/2013    ExamB             2/1/2013      2/1/2013
  5    George    2/5/2013    TreatmentA                      2/1/2013
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't give you down vote, but I still don't know how to achieve what I am trying with nvl and lag.

Comment: Mowgli - I clearly wrote to you: create sample data, means create tables, populate with data. Do you expect we would do this for you? Or you want an example on any table? Will it help you? I will post one that is works and tested. But you will not be able to test it. You should downvote yourself.

Comment: Art, I didn't downvote you, and I am not expert in sql I didn't know what you meant by sample data till I saw alex's post.